# Zend Framework: What exception to use for "Access denied"/"unauthorized access" from ACL?

Tags: zend-framework, authorization, zend-acl

i am using Zend Framework `Zend_Acl` i am wanting to throw an exception when the user is denied access to a resource. which exception class do i use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK you don't have a specific exception for that, if that's what you're asking. Create your own exception class which extends from `Zend_Exception` and throw that.

Comment: can i say that such exception classes are just for the purposes for readability in code, and does nothing too different from 1 another?

Comment: readability, plus based on the type of the exception or the exception code, you can do different things in the error controller (access denied, page not found, application error, etc...).

Comment: with `Zend_Exception`, i can also set the code right? `void   __construct  ([string $msg = ''], [int $code = 0], [ $previous = null]) `. the 2nd param?

Comment: and you can catch different types of exceptions, enabling your application to ignore issues that you expect to happen and deal with yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
throw new Zend_Controller_Action_Exception('Forbidden', 403);
```